# Entry in .npmignore doesn't work

Tags: git, npm, gitignore, npmignore

I'd like to keep source (`/ts/**/*.ts`) files only in remote git repo, and transpilation results (`/js/**/*.js`) - only in resulting npm package.
In order to achieve that I've added these entries in ignore-files:

#### .gitignore

```
/js
...
```

#### .npmignore

```
/ts
```

Remote repository doesn't contain `/js` folder, so `.gitignore` works fine.
But it looks like entry in `.npmignore` doesn't work, because I get `/ts` folder with its contents on `npm i <package>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did this folder exist when you changed the .gitignore ? If so, remove the git cache.

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov: I believe this is outside the scope of OP, but git tells me that either `/js: '/js' is outside repository` or `pathspec 'js' did not match any files`. But every single file / directory I've mentioned is in the root folder!

Comment: Try without the first /

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov: That's a second error (`'js' did not match any files`).

Comment: Try `js/*` also i never saw ** in gitignore

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov: Still the second error. I'll try to investigate on this issue separately. Meanwhile, is the `.npmignore` file's content correct?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore... sorry.. hhhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still didn't get the point of the issue, some of these helped:

- re-clone the repo from scratch into another folder
- run `npm doctor`
- change entry in `.npmignore` to `./ts`

So now the `/ts` folder is not being downloaded on `npm i <package>` and no fatal error occur.

Comment: My issue was that I had the `.npmignore` file in the root folder and it must belong to a subfolder to be effective